Microsoft Graph API sometimes return less channel messages than expected
I use Microsoft Graph API to get messages in a Team channel.
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/f25d16eb-34d2-4028-9598-a3ada02f8ed6/channels/19:e_oZqwczEi2Llv55cLYUGaK5b_FLfLiGgdkqe3Htf6I1@thread.tacv2/messages?$top=50&$expand=replies

However, I found that num of the returned messages could be less than total messages in channel.
(ex: I have 36 messages in total , but sometimes got 35, 28  messages)
I was sure that the nextLink or deltaLink were empty.
I wrote a script which calls the API repeatedly for 50 times, and had this issue 8 times.
I also tried on different $top value from 5 to 50, or remove $expand query, but the issue still persists
